# What did I do wrong with mxGetPr

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

Please consider this excerpt of code within `mexFunction`

```
\\cppfunc.cpp

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[]){

  \\...Parts where I check the number of lhs and rhs

  double* upper = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
  double* lower = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
  double* grids = mxGetPr(prhs[2]);

  mexPrintf("upper 1=%d  \n\n", upper[0] ); 

}
```

I planned to call my mex function like this `cppfunc([1 2 3], [1 2 3], [1 2 3])`. Basically, it takes in three `MATLAB` vectors and prints out the first element of the first input vector through `mexPrintf`. The output should be `1`. However, it returns:

`upper 1=3`.

It seems to me that the function is returning the length of the first input vector. For example, if I do `cppfunc([1 2 3 4], [1 2 3], [1 2 3])`, it would return `upper 1=4`.

I thought I was right by using `%d` in my call to `mexPrintf` since `mxGetPr` converts the input to an array of doubles. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format `%d` is for integers values of type `int`. You have to use `%f` for `double`s.
See [documentation of printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).